# How to make a simple task queue

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm looking to create a simple Task Queue with RabbitMQ and PHP's PECL extension named AMQP.

My objective is fairly simple :
Producers should send messages to a specific queue containing an enveloppe of the object that needs to be processed.

Consumers should all listen to said queue and process messages as they come.
I need to be able to add more Consumers and let RabbitMq dispatch the messages in a roundrobin fashion.

Although this is very easy to find tutorials for the python or java libraries, i wasn't able to find any for PHP's PECL library.

I'm not quite sure if i should bind anything, i had a working example with a custom php library that used "basic_publish and basic_consume" which are not implemented in such way in the PECL lib.

So here's what i got so far :
Publisher :

```php
$oConfig = Zend_Registry::get('config');
$sQueue = $oConfig->amqp->validate_queue_name;

$oConnection = new AMQPConnection();
$oConnection->setLogin($oConfig->amqp->login);
$oConnection->setPassword($oConfig->amqp->pass);
$oConnection->setVhost($oConfig->amqp->vhost);
$oConnection->setPort($oConfig->amqp->port);
$oConnection->connect();

$oChannel = new AMQPChannel($oConnection);
$oExchange = new AMQPExchange($oChannel);

$sMsg = new stdClass();
$sMsg->nId = $p_nId;
$sMsg->nStatus= $p_nStatus;
try  {
  $oChannel->startTransaction();
  $bResponse = $oExchange->publish($sMgs,$sQueue);
  if (!$bResponse)  {
    echo "<h1>An error occured, the message can't be published</h1>";
    echo "<h3>Sorry i don't know why</h3>";
    exit;
  }
  $oChannel->commitTransaction();
}  catch (Exception $oException)  {
  echo "<h1>An error occured, the message can't be published</h1>";
  echo "<h3>See error below</h3>";
  echo "<pre>";
  echo print_r($oException->getMessage());
  echo "</pre>";
  exit;
}
```

Worker

```php
  $oConfig = Zend_Registry::get('config');
  $oConnection = new AMQPConnection();
  $oConnection->setLogin($oConfig->amqp->login);
  $oConnection->setPassword($oConfig->amqp->pass);
  $oConnection->setVhost($oConfig->amqp->vhost);
  $oConnection->setPort($oConfig->amqp->port);
  $oConnection->connect();

  $oChannel = new AMQPChannel($oConnection);
  $oQueue = new AMQPQueue($oChannel);

  $oQueue->declare($oConfig->amqp->validate_queue_name);

  function processMessage($oMessage, $oQueue) {
    $nId     = $msg->body->nId;
    $nStatus = $msg->body->nStatus;
    $oIniAct = $oActionMap->findBy('id',$nId);

    $sReply  = $oIniAct->updateStatusMisc($nStatus);
    if ($sReply->status == $nStatus)  {
      $oQueue->ack($sMsg['delivery_tag']);
    } else {
    $oQueue->nack($sMsg['delivery_tag'],AMQP_REQUEUE);
    }
  }

  $oQueue->consume("processMessage",AMQP_NOPARAM);
```

What PHP doc tells me is that consume() will lock the according thread for everyone? so basically i can only have one working worker at a time?
Also i see that people are binding queues, but the first worker example with basic consume that i saw didnt use that.

As you can see i'm pretty confused, any help/ direction/ tutorials ASO... would help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has synchronous nature, so yes, `consume()` will lock main thread while underlying logic is to read all incoming data on socket connection, translate it to PHP structures and feed to your consumer function.

There was discussion in issues on github to make php-amqp asynchronous but we all agreed that if someone need asynchronous features PHP is not the best language for that, by design.

Personally I run consumer script multiple time (in fact i have balancer for that), so each consumer doesn't affect each other, they may fail and restart independently. I think you can do the same.

I run consumer script multiple time at once as daemon and balancer script (no real load balancer, in fact) which monitor consumers activity (done via memcache, not clear, but WFM) and when there are no activity on consumers balancer kill them one by one (but at least one working consumer should still alive). When consumers are overloaded balancer script start more consumers.

If you need consume one message and then die let your consumer function return `false`.

If you sure queue has at least one message available you may want to use `AMQPQueue::get()` method which will not block (or at least shouldn't) your main thread.

Comment: What do you mean ? you run consumer scripts behind a load balancer? I'm not sure i understand. Basically if i just have two occurences of that worker code, it won't work? 
How do you do it you have your worker consuming just one message and instantly dying?
All of this is very unclear to me:s

Comment: Updated my answer. Maybe get() will fit your needs then?

Comment: actually i think i'm ok with blocking my main thread. I think i understood that multiple consumers will be able to work in a parralelized way just fine.
Basically that's a misunderstanding from me, that you and a bunch of reading clarfied.
Thanks!